# Check enumerate counter for custom labels

Tags: enumerate, counters

I want to create a custom enumerate environment specifically for algorithms:
The First \item should have the label `Input:`
The second \item should have the label `Output:`
From then on, have the standard (\arabic*) counter.
This is, what it should look like:

[image]

I got the counter offset to work, but I can't figure out how to check the counter for the two first items.
How can I do that?
I already tried all kinds of combinations of `algo`, `algoi`, `thealgo`, `\thealgo` and `\value{...}` etc., all if which result in the following:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\newcommand{\step}{
    \ifthenelse{ \equal{\value{algoi}}{-2} }
        { \item[Input: ]}
        { \ifthenelse { \equal{\value{algoi}}{-1} }
            {\item[Output: ]}
            {\item }
        }
    }

\newenvironment{algo}{\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*), start = -1]}{\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algo}
        \step This is the input.
        \step This is the output.
        \step This is step 1.
        \step This is step 2.
    \end{algo}
\end{document}
```

This code will throw the error message `` You can't use `\relax' after \the. \step `` twice for each `\step`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd avoid `\ifthenelse`. Here's a way that also allows to have automatic good alignment to the left margin.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\steplabel}{m}
 {
  \xoriun_steplabel_std:n { #1 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\steplabelref}{m}
 {
  \xoriun_steplabel_ref:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \xoriun_steplabel_std:n
 {
  \__xoriun_steplabel:nnn { ( } { ) } { #1 }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \xoriun_steplabel_ref:n
 {
  \__xoriun_steplabel:nnn { } { } { #1 }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__xoriun_steplabel:nnn
 {
  \int_case:nnF { \value{#3} }
   {
    {-1}{Input:}
    {0}{Output:}
   }
   {#1\arabic{#3}#2}
 }
\AddEnumerateCounter{\steplabel}{\xoriun_steplabel_std:n}{Output:}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\steplabelref}{\xoriun_steplabel_ref:n}{Output:}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\let\step\item

\newenvironment{algo}
 {\begin{enumerate}[label=\steplabel*,ref=\steplabelref*,start=-1,leftmargin=*]}
 {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algo}
        \step This is the input.
        \step This is the output.
        \step This is step 1.\label{test}
        \step This is step 2.
    \end{algo}

\ref{test}
\end{document}
```

I define two new counter representations, namely `\steplabel` and `\steplabelref`, the latter to avoid parentheses around the step number.
Next the two representations are registered with `enumitem`.

[image]

If you want parentheses around the step numbers in cross-references, just remove the `ref=` key.

Comment: thank you, this works really nicely. I don't care so much about the `\ifthenelse`, but the alignment is really nice.

Answer (score 1):

There is no counter `algoi`, in enumerate it is called `enumi`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}


\newcommand{\step}{
    \ifthenelse{ \equal{\value{enumi}}{-2} }
        { \item[Input: ]\stepcounter{enumi}}
        { \ifthenelse { \equal{\value{enumi}}{-1} }
            {\item[Output: ]\stepcounter{enumi}}
            {\item }
        }
    }
\newenvironment{algo}{\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*), start = -1]}{\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algo}
        \step This is the input.
        \step This is the output.
        \step This is step 1.
        \step This is step 2.
    \end{algo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. Btw, why is the ``\stepcounter`` necessary? Bc when using ``\item[...]`` it would increment, or did I get this wrong?

Comment: Try it out  ... then you will see if it increments or not.

Comment: First I didn't see that ``\stepcounter`` was added so I know it doesn't work, but I wanted to know why it doesn't work. If there is a simple explanation for it or is just low level TeX weirdness?